# Delete all nodes in a doubly linked list with recursion

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

I'm trying to write a function that deletes all nodes in a linked list with a given value, but I want to try it with a recursive function. I think the block of code for deleting the last node in the list is inadvertently setting the entire list to null, but I don't know how to fix that.

EDIT: The entire list is not supposed to be null, it is supposed to delete all nodes that hold the given integer. For example, if the given list was 3->4->3->6 and we wanted to delete all instances of 3, the list would be 4->6

```
typedef struct nodeStruct {
   int num;
   struct nodeStruct *next;
   struct nodeStruct *prev;
}node;

 node* deleteNode(node* head, int num) {
  node* current = head;
  if (current == NULL) {
      return head;
  } else if (current->num == num) {
      if (current->prev == NULL) {
          head = current->next;//delete first Node
          head->prev = NULL;
          free(current);
          head = deleteNode(head, num);
      } else if (current->next == NULL) {
          free(current);//delete last node
          return head;
      } else {
          current->prev->next = current->next; //delete middle node
          current->next->prev = current->prev;
          free(current);
          head = deleteNode(head, num);
      }
  } else {
      head = deleteNode(current->next, num);
  }
  return head;
}
```

Comment: "setting the entire list to null". Isn't that what is supposed to happen? An empty list is typically one where the entire list is NULL. Please provide a [mcve] and state the expected behaviour and actual behaviour.

Comment: A list is a bad data type for recursion. Better use an iteration.

Comment: `head = current->next;//delete first Node
          head->prev = NULL;` : It is necessary to check that `head` is not `NULL` before `head->prev = NULL;`.

Comment: @Skyler Gunn  Due to this code block  else {
      head = deleteNode(current->next, num);
  } the function will always return NULL because this code if (current == NULL) {
      return head;
  } is the condition to stop the recursion.:)

Comment: Be very aware that for every recursive call a complete function stack is created and you incur all function overhead for each recursive call. For large lists, this quickly adds up. Olaf's point is well taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this

```
if(head == NULL){
    return NULL;
} else {
    node *rest = deleteNode(head->next, num);
    if(head->num == num){
        if(rest != NULL){
            rest->prev = NULL;
        }
        free(head);
        return rest;
    } else {
        if(rest != NULL){
            rest->prev = head;
        }
        head->next = rest;
        return head;
    }
}
```